# How do I create typeset a document containing obscure Chinese characters?

Tags: xetex, symbols, xecjk

I have a document with a mix of English, simplified and traditional Chinese characters, and some obscure characters that are typically only used as components in other characters. I'm trying to typeset it in XeTeX like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{chinese}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\begin{document}
Simplified Characters 简体字子曰学而时习之不亦说乎有朋自远方来不亦乐乎 
Traditional Characters 繁体字子曰學而時習之不亦說乎有朋自遠方來不亦樂乎 
Obscure characters ⺼
\end{document}
```

This works except for the three obscure characters , ⺼, and .

If I do `\setCJKmainfont{SimSun-ExtB}`, then  and  will render correctly but everything else will become boxes.

If I do `\setCJKmainfont{PMingLiU}`, then ⺼ and the simplified and traditional characters will render correctly, but  and  will become boxes.

Is there any way to get all the characters I want to use to render correctly at the same time? Preferably, I'd be able to enter the text as-is without having to add any special containers for font-switching.

Comment: I can't even see the *obscure* characters in my browser :-)

Comment: I can score two of possible three points with `\usepackage[fallback]{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[FallBack=SimSun-ExtB]{SimSun}`. This ⺼ is too obscure for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not too proud about my ⺼-trick, but if you just need it a few times...

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{chinese}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage[AutoFallBack=true]{xeCJK}[2016/05/14]
\setCJKmainfont[FallBack=SimSun-ExtB]{SimSun}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
    Simplified Characters 简体字子曰学而时习之不亦说乎有朋自远方来不亦乐乎 

    Traditional Characters 繁体字子曰學而時習之不亦說乎有朋自遠方來不亦樂乎 

    Obscure characters \setCJKfallbackfamilyfont{rm}{PMingLiU}⺼\setCJKfallbackfamilyfont{rm}{SimSun-ExtB}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can manage working with that. I'll accept if nobody comes up with a more elegant solution in the next few days or so.